# Image Transition on `onmouseover`

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this code to change from one image to another:

`<img title="Hello" src="selfie.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='hero_image.png'" onmouseout="this.src='selfie.jpg'" />`

I need help with the code so I can slow the transition from one image to the next.

Comment: Please provide mode details like code snippet or codepen so someone can answer to your question

Comment: Please refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As soon as an image loads it paints, no transitions can be made on that. I recommend you to keep both loaded inside a box, to listen the box event and then transition from one image to other with `opacity`, `transform` or whatever effect you want to achieve.

Comment: So with my current code, is there no way to to slow down the transition from one image to another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I add an animation to my onmouseover javascript function(changing image on hover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951714/how-do-i-add-an-animation-to-my-onmouseover-javascript-functionchanging-image-o)

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution to this would be rendering the two images and changing their [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) instead of changing `src` for the same tag. Something like :

```
<div id="container">
  <img class="bottom" src="hero_image.png" />
  <img class="top" src="selfie.svg" />
</div>
```

Once you are playing with the `opacity`, the [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) effect can be applied using the following `CSS` :

```
#container img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#container img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: It's so identical to the comment that you even left the `transform` in place while talking about `transition` btw, but it's fine. Just fix that.

Comment: @Leo My bad, I keep mixing these terms. Updated.